# CSS image hover / scale works great in chrome but not IE

Tags: css, image, hover, scale, opacity

I am working on a website and i have a horizontal table with 4 images that I want to scale larger when hovered. I also have an opacity effect that they become solid when hovered on. It works great on chrome but they images are at 100% opacity and do not scale larger when hovered on IE.

**jsfiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/u9hk6x5y/

```
#hoverimage {
    text-align:center;  
    margin-left:13%;
    margin-right:13%;
    z-index: 9999;  
}

#hoverimage1 {
    width: 162px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    z-index:9999;
}

#hoverimage2 {
    width: 162px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    z-index: 9999;
}

#hoverimage3 {
    width: 162px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    z-index: 9999;
}

#hoverimage4 {
    width: 162px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    z-index: 9999;
}

#hovergallery{
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s; /*Webkit: Animation duration*/
-moz-transition-duration: 0.5s; /*Mozilla duration version*/
-o-transition-duration: 0.5s; /*Opera duration version*/
transition-duration: 0.5s;
opacity: 0.8; /*initial opacity of images*/
margin: 0 20px 10px 0; /*margin between images*/
}

#hovergallery:hover{
-webkit-transform:scale(1.4); /*Webkit: Scale up image to 1.2x original size*/
-moz-transform:scale(1.4); /*Mozilla scale version*/
-o-transform:scale(1.4); /*Opera scale version*/
-ms-transform:scale(1.4);
transform: scale(1.4);
opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: What version of IE? Pretty sure <=7 do not support :hover on anything but anchors.

Comment: I am using IE 11, most recent version

Comment: Can you post your markup? And maybe a jsFiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u9hk6x5y/ there is a jfiddle for it

Comment: i have ie 11.096 and it works fine

Comment: if the jfiddle works in IE does that mean the code is correct? it could be some of my other code interfering with it. Kinda new to this, thanks!

Comment: maybe - sorry fpr delayed reply i was on the phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said `4 images`, but using `id selector`, change that to `class selector`, since id must be unique per page

**UPDATE**

This is what I said (do this for all your `<img />` tags, btw I just checked and worked fine on IE, Chrome & Firefox.

```
<img class="hovergallery" height="240px" width="162px"  src="images/toolreconditioninggraphic.png" />

.hovergallery{
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    opacity: 0.8;
    margin: 0 20px 10px 0;
 }

 .hovergallery:hover{
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.4);
    -moz-transform:scale(1.4);
    -o-transform:scale(1.4);
    -ms-transform:scale(1.4);
    transform: scale(1.4);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: do you mean change the <img id="hovergallery" to class="hovergallary"  ? i tried that and it didnt work at all, even in chrome

Comment: Yes, must change in both of `HTML` & `CSS`, did you?

Comment: Fixed it, made the changes you suggested and got rid of some of the other css that i had created while trying to fix it and never deleted. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome, just be careful about using `id selector` & `class selector`, also I recommended you, using `attributes selector` too, also please remove `<center>...</center>` and using `CSS` instead of that, because this tag is already dead, of course this is just an offer :)

Comment: I have a lot of cleaning up to do on the code, i appreciate the help !